# Conflicting JS with Popup contact Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a popup contact form on a HTML site, and I'm running into a js conflict. I'm stuck with how to get everything on the site to work, because removing some of the js calls causes certain functionality to stop working. I'm sure for this community of experts, my error is probably evident and simple; nonetheless I could really use some help figuring it out. I've included my code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <!-- Basic -->
    <title>iMAR Affiliate</title>
    <meta content="DSA79" name="author" />
    <meta content="responsive, html5 template, one page, landing, startup, business, company, corporate, creative" name="keywords" />
    <meta content="iMAR Affiliate" name="description" /><!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport" /><!-- Libs CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- On Scroll Animations -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- Template CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- Responsive CSS -->
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- Image Slider -->
    <link href="js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900italic,900,700italic,400italic,300italic,300,100italic,100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="html5ModalContact.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.html5ModalContact.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){          

        $().html5ModalContact({
                // Popup Config
                method: "post",
                action: "process_form.php",
                shadow: "#FFFFFF",
                opacity: 70,
                advanced_close: false,
                // Fields Enabled
                firstn_on: true,
                lastn_on: false,
                email_on: true,
                subject_on: true,
                phone_on: false,
                // Field Labels
                firstn_label: 'Your First Name',
                lastn_label: 'Your Last Name',
                email_label: 'Your Email Address',
                subject_label:  'Message Subject',
                phone_label: 'Your Phone Number',
                message_label: 'Message',
                submit_label: 'Submit',
                close_label: 'Close',
                // Other
                subject_values: 'General,Technical,Feedback,Comments,Help and Support'
        });

});

</script>
</head>
<body><!-- HEADER
        ============================================= -->
<header id="header">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container"><!-- Logo & Responsive Menu -->
<div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navigation-menu" data-toggle="collapse" id="nav-toggle" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#top-page-banner"><img alt="logo" role="banner" src="img/iMAR2014Logo.png" /></a></div>
<!-- /.navbar-header --><!-- Navigation -->

<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-menu" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a class="selected-nav" href="#intro" id="GoToHome">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-1" id="GoToAbout">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="">Brochure</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features" id="GoToFeatures">Benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faq" id="GoToFaq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clients" id="GoToClients">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://50.87.154.1/~imarf/contact.html" id="GoToHome">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse --></div>
<!-- /.container --></div>
<!-- /.navbar --></header>
<!-- END HEADER --><!-- CONTENT WRAPPER
        ============================================= -->

<div id="content-wrapper"><!-- ABOUT-1
            ============================================= -->
```

```
<footer id="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="row"><!-- Footer Navigation -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="footer_nav">
<ul class="footer-nav clearfix">
    <li><a href="http://50.87.154.1/~imarf/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="footer_copy">
<p>&copy; iMAR Entertainment Inc. 2007-2014</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Footer Navigation --><

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="col-sm-12" id="newsletter_form">
<div class="clearfix">
<form action="newsletter.php" class="subscribe-form pull-right" id="subscribe-form" method="post"><input class="subscribe-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." type="email" /><button class="subscribe-submit" type="submit">Subscribe</button></form>
</div>

<p class="pull-right" id="newsletter-paragraph">Join our newsletter subscription, be always informed</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Newsletter Form --></div>
<!-- End row --></div>
<!-- End container --></footer>
<!-- END FOOTER --></div>
<!-- END CONTENT WRAPPER --><!-- EXTERNAL SCRIPTS
        ============================================= --><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/retina.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/jquery.accordion.source.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/owl.carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/animations.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]--><!-- Google Analytics: Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. Go to http://www.google.com/analytics/ for more information. --><!--
        <script>
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
        --></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest making a page that has the minimal functionality required to demonstrate the problem, as opposed to a wall-o-code.

Comment: Alright, i've pared it down some to show the scripts i'm running, and the source of the potential conflict.

Comment: What is the exact error that is happening in Console?

Comment: I'm seeing these errors in Console: ReferenceError Can't find variable jQuery & TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$().html5ModalContact')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably loading a jQuery extension before you are loading jQuery.

Change the order of your script tags to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.html5ModalContact.js"></script>
```

Then the `Can't find variable jQuery & TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$().html5ModalContact')` error should be gone.